# Book for multivariable calculus

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, mathematics, calculus

Hi I want to start learning multi variable calculus specifically for learning electrodynamics. What are some good text books?

Comment: I would think that the one required for your multivariate calculus math course would be an obvious choice.

Comment: The one I learnt from as an undergrad was Stewart's book: "multivariable calculus". I quite liked it, lots of examples. If you want a thicker more comprehensive book with calculus and other things in there that has lots of physics and engineering applications I would recommend Kreyszig's "advanced engineering mathematics".

Comment: At least as a supplement, I recommend [this undergraduate book by Shankar](http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Training-Mathematics-Fitness-Students/dp/0306450364)

Comment: I understand that in principle you should just be able to learn the topic with the correct text.  However, in practice at that level, I would highly suggest taking a course as there is a lot more to the learning experience than simply having the information.

Comment: susan colley's Vector Calculus text is more at the level you need. Also, my notes: http://www.supermath.info/MultivariateCalculus.html are ripe with errors and good ideas.